# Why can the elements of $L^\infty$ be approximated in $L^p$ by $C^1$-functions?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, approximation, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain and $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. From which theorem does the existence of $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C^1(\overline\Omega)$ with $$f_k\stackrel{L^p(\Omega)}{\to}f$$ for some $p>n$ folow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any $p\in[1,\infty)$.

First, since $\Omega$ is bounded, $L^\infty(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$. Say $\epsilon>0$. Choose $K\subset\Omega$ with $K$ compact, so that if $g=f\chi_K$ then $$||f-g||_p<\epsilon.$$

Now if $\phi_n$ is a smooth approximate identity with compact support then the convolution $g*\phi_n$ is smooth, $$||g-g*\phi_n||_p\to0,$$and if $n$ is large enough then $g*\phi_n$ is supported in a compact subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: Note that $n$ is the considered dimension in the question. I assume you're referring to a sequence $(\phi_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of "smooth" functions $\phi_k$. What exactly is meant by "smooth"? $\phi_k\in C^1(\Omega)$ or even $\phi_k\in C^\infty(\Omega)$?

Comment: Yes, too many $n$'s, sorry. (This is why I tend to talk about $\Bbb R^d$ instead of $\Bbb R^n$.) By smooth I meant infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to show that characteristics of intervals can be approximated in $L^p$ norm, and then extend this result arbitrary measurable sets  (using the regularity of the Lebesgue measure). Finally extend this result to simple functions.

This is also Lusin Theorem. Whose main idea is to use Urysohn's functions. So the answer of your why question is because of the regularity of the lebesgue measure which read as follows  $$\forall \; C \subset \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}^n)\text{ and } \epsilon>0 \; \text{ there are $K_{\epsilon}$ compact and $A_\epsilon$ open such that } K_\epsilon\subset C \subset A_\epsilon\; \lambda(A_\epsilon \setminus K_\epsilon) <\epsilon$$

Comment: Is $p>n$ crucial?

Comment: no, it suffices $p\geq1$

Comment: Your statement of regularity is wrong. What's true is that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can get $\lambda(A\setminus K)<\epsilon$. (What you said doesn't follow because a countable intersection of open sets is not open, and a countable union of compact sets is not compact. You can also get a $G_\delta$ set $A$ and an $F_\sigma$ set $K$ with $K\subset C\subset A$ and $\lambda(A\setminus K)=0$.)

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Ullrich, you are right!